# Strange difference in behavior on CSS Transition from Chrome 68 to 69

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

Recently, while continuing work on a chrome extension, I noticed that the update from 68 to 69 caused some undesirable behavior.

I have an iframe that is "minimized" by appending a class containing `right: -360px` (thus pushing it off screen) and is "maximized" by removing that class and having `right: 0px;` (thus displaying the iframe on the right side of the screen).

This all seems to work fine. However, I also have

```
transition: width 0.5s, right 0.5s;
```

to provide a "sliding animation" when these actions occur. In Chrome 68, this all worked fine (with the iframe filling the proper space). However in Chrome 69, the iframe appears to render at the "initial point" prior to transition, and only one small portion is shown. It appears to work this way, because when I set the transition timer shorter, more of the iframe is shown. If I remove the transition all entirely, the entire iframe is shown perfectly upon click.

A temporary fix would be to remove the transition for the time being. But I would prefer to avoid that. Is there any other potential solution I could use?

Thank you.

Comment: Hard to answer these questions without a URL or complete code. Would you be able to provide these?

Comment: An [mcve] would be very helpful, and developing one is often informative to the problem anyway (sometimes you'll find you suddenly can't replicate in a clean environment, and realize the issue isn't where you thought for example)

Comment: Yep, good point -  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - That's what I meant ;)

Comment: One for my list of inexplicable breaking changes between Chrome versions...

Comment: So I tried a minimal, complete and verifiable example. However, it seemed to only be reproducable through using a chrome extension. And using an iframe within an iframe.

Comment: Chrome 69 is doing this for me as well. Literally everything that has a css transition is transitioned from browser default to my css on page load. Without the transitions the default browser state is never showed however. No other browser is showing this behaviour except for Chrome 69

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your issue - try not using `width` transition here at all. 
If you need to show that iframe in certain space of a page (not on the right border of a screen) you could use container wrapper with `overflow: hidden`.

Please check: http://jsbin.com/lamejumigu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript onLoad

You could load the iFrame after the page has loaded using the [onLoad](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event.

```
<body onload="load-iFrame()">
```

### CSS Animations & Delay

You can also use the [animation-delay](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp) and [keyframe animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) rather than transitions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    animation-delay: 2s;
 opacity: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {opacity: 0; right: -360px;}
    to {opacity: 1; right: 0;}
}
@keyframes mymove { 
    from {opacity: 0; right: -360px;}
    to {opacity: 1; right: 0;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Keyframe Animations</h1>
<p>Replace the block with an iFrame</p>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```